# How to turn on Flash?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

There is a little flash app called [easing function generator](http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm), I used it for a long time and since adobe flash is deprecated now I wanna port it to vue/angular/react, but flash refuses to turn on in chrome, chromium, mozilla firefox, pale moon and opera.

How can I turn flash on in chrome/chromium to view the app? Or maybe in some other browser

I know flash is dead, but it is dead for users, not for developers. Developers should have an option to run flash apps,

Comment: Flash is dead...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, maybe, but there must be a way the one can execute flash app. SIMULA 67 is dead, brainfuck was stillborn, but i still can run programs that use them

Answer (score 1):

Solution is found!

First of all, install old version of desired browser - [chrome](http://old-dos.ru/index.php?page=files&mode=files&do=show&id=7207), [firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/15.0/win32/en-GB/) or [opera](https://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/). Then install old version of Flash Player, [11.1.102.55](http://old-dos.ru/index.php?page=files&mode=files&do=show&id=1769) for instance. That's it, now you can run any flash application in browser!

If something doesn't work, try to repeat both steps in some virtual machine - windows xp or 2000

Also you can run flash apps in Macromedia Flash and Adobe Flash Player standalone, its often marked with "sa" in file name